# How do I migrate a nifi 1.10.0 flow.xml.gz to 1.14 or newer versions: sensitive properties

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-toolkit

I have a dataflow running in NiFi 1.10.0, the relevant properties from this installation is here:

```
nifi.sensitive.props.key=
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
nifi.sensitive.props.provider=BC
nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=
```

I am trying to migrate the flowfile to the 1.15.2 install where the properties are

```
 nifi.sensitive.props.key=<redacted>
 nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
 nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=NIFI_PBKDF2_AES_GCM_256
 nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=
```

Found this section in the [NiFi admin guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#nifi_sensitive_props_key) to help with the migration.
Has anyone done this, what command options did you use?
Also is this a two step process since I am going from a blank key to a non-empty one and also changing the algorithm at the same time?

I used this command and the conversion works fine when you don't change the algorithm. Basically just setting a key when it was not set in the earlier 1.10.0 install.

```
 $ ./nifi-toolkit-1.15.2/bin/encrypt-config.sh -f /path/to/nifi/nifi-1.10.0/conf/flow.xml.gz -g /path/to/nifi/nifi-1.15.2/conf/flow.xml.gz -s new_password -n /path/to/nifi/nifi-1.10.0/conf/nifi.properties -o /path/to/nifi/nifi-1.15.2/conf/nifi.properties -x
```

How do you change the algorithm and set the key at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. The example command works as-is for me as well. According to the documentation (https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#encrypt_config_tool), we can use `-A` to specify a new algorithm. I didn't test it though

Comment: I  will give it a try

Comment: No, the -A flag didn't work. It did't output the nifi.properties file with the new algorithm name I provide in the command. However it does set the specified value for the nifi.sensitive.props.key property in the output nifi.properties

Comment: hi @VijayKumar Have you got any solution for the issue?

Comment: Hi Priyesh, yes I did have this resolved.

Comment: If the versions are different, Do you want to open another question and I can chime in there.

Comment: @VijayKumar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74095159/how-to-migrate-nif-flowfile-from-1-12-version-to-1-16-3. You can answer here

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be resolved by following steps

1. Before migration if you don't have nifi.sensitive.props.key set, set it using following command `${NIFI_TOOLKIT_PAT}/bin/encrypt-config.sh -f /opt/nifi/nifi-current/data/flow.xml.gz -p ${NIFI_HOME}/conf/nifi.properties -s <NEW_KEY_TO_SET> -x`
2. Once key is set upgrade nifi. Since in newer version algorithm is changed set it using command  `${NIFI_HOME}/bin/nifi.sh set-sensitive-properties-algorithm <NEW_ALGORITHM>`
3. Once algorithm set, encrypt again using command `${NIFI_TOOLKIT_PAT}/bin/encrypt-config.sh -f /opt/nifi/nifi-current/data/flow.xml.gz -p ${NIFI_HOME}/conf/nifi.properties -s <NEW_KEY_TO_SET> -x`

Now you will get all compatible files with respect your latest version