# Getting OutOfMemoryError from Nifi encryptconfig command

Tags: apache-nifi

Getting following exception while executing command

```
./encrypt-config.sh -n $NIFI_HOME/conf/nifi.properties  -f /opt/nifi/data/flow.xml.gz -s password -x
```

`ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.toolkit.encryptconfig.EncryptConfigMain: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332) at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124) at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:596) at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:190) at org.apache.commons.io.output.StringBuilderWriter.write(StringBuilderWriter.java:142) at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2538) at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2516) at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2493) at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2441) at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:1084) at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils$toString.call(Unknown Source) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) at org.apache.nifi.properties.ConfigEncryptionTool$_loadFlowXml_closure3$_closure29.doCall(ConfigEncryptionTool.groovy:666) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294) at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022) at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414) at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods.withCloseable(IOGroovyMethods.java:1622) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods.withCloseable(NioGroovyMethods.java:1759) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ReflectionMetaMethod.invoke(ReflectionMetaMethod.java:54) Java heap space`

Tried increasing the memory after seeing following forum.
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Getting-OutOfMemoryError-from-Nifi-encryptconfig/td-p/284446

But issue is not getting resolved. Can anyone help

Comment: can you tell the version that you used now?

Comment: @PriyeshKaratha I used nifi 1.12.1 version

Comment: You have to upgrade your nifi. You can check my answer and accept it if it helps to you. If you are upgrading nifi please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74095159/how-to-migrate-nif-flowfile-from-1-12-version-to-1-16-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an issue reported in older version and seems like fixed in nifi 1.13.0
You can refer  following JIRA ticket.

This issue will happen if you are using flowfile with large data. You have to either clean up the flowfile or you need to upgrade to 1.13.0 version before upgrading to latest version.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6999

Note : If you are not upgrading then you can clean some of the nifi templates mannually in nifi UI and make less size for flowfile.xml.gz if its applicable. Then we can upgrade to higher.

Comment: Thanks tried upgrading to 1.13.0 version and its resolved